# Creating Unique Data Frame from Two Lists

Tags: python

I have two lists, and I'm trying to create a matrix (or data frame) of the number of times values from list2 are in each sub-list of list1:

```
list1 = [['texas','california','illinois'],['illinois','montana'],['new york','iowa'],['florida'],['north carolina']]
list2 = ['california','illinois','maine','oregon','wisconsin','florida']

count = 0
countx = 0
i = 0

for item in list1:
    while i < len(list2):
        x = list1[count].count(list2[countx])
        print(list2[countx],x)
        countx = countx + 1
        i = i + 1
```

Output:

```
california 1
illinois 1
maine 0
oregon 0
wisconsin 0
florida 0
```

The code above loops through the first sublist and prints an output. I'm not sure how to make it move to the next sublist while making sure list2 is also being looped through.

My end vision is to have matrix that has each sub list on the left hand side and the column headers be list 2.

```
                                   california  illinois  maine  oregon  wisconsin  florida
['texas','california','illinois']     1           1        0      0        0          0 
['illinois','montana']                0           1        0      0        0          0  
etc.
```

Comment: Why do you want a list to be the index value for each row in your DataFrame? Can you give an example of how you'd expect to use this DataFrame, that makes it clear why having something  like `['illinois','montana']` as an index value is useful?

Answer (score 1):

Use `pandas.Series.str.contains`:

```
s = pd.Series(list1)
df = pd.DataFrame({k: s.str.contains(k, regex=False) 
                   for k in list2},
                  dtype=int).set_index(s)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                               california  illinois  maine  oregon  wisconsin  \
[texas, california, illinois]           1         1      0       0          0   
[illinois, montana]                     0         1      0       0          0   
[new york, iowa]                        0         0      0       0          0   
[florida]                               0         0      0       0          0   
[north carolina]                        0         0      0       0          0   

                               florida  
[texas, california, illinois]        0  
[illinois, montana]                  0  
[new york, iowa]                     0  
[florida]                            1  
[north carolina]                     0
```

Answer (score 1):

Although it's not clear what the value will be of having lists as index values, here's fairly simple bit of code that does exactly what you ask:

```
import pandas as pd

list1 = [['texas', 'california', 'illinois'],
         ['illinois', 'montana'],
         ['new york', 'iowa'],
         ['florida'],
         ['north carolina']]
list2 = ['california', 'illinois', 'maine', 'oregon', 'wisconsin', 'florida']

df = pd.DataFrame()
for x1 in list1:
    df = df.append(pd.DataFrame([[x1, *[x1.count(x2) for x2 in list2]]], columns=['index', *list2]).set_index('index'))

print(df)
```

Result:

```
                               california  illinois  ...  wisconsin  florida
index                                                ...                    
[texas, california, illinois]           1         1  ...          0        0
[illinois, montana]                     0         1  ...          0        0
[new york, iowa]                        0         0  ...          0        0
[florida]                               0         0  ...          0        1
[north carolina]                        0         0  ...          0        0

[5 rows x 6 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fast to implement but slow in time, way to do it.

```py
for item2 in list2:
    count = 0
    for l in list1:
        for item in l:
            if item == item2:
                count += 1
    print(item2, count)
```

I realised this doesn't create a matrix.